# Spring security configuration not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring security. I noticed that as soon as I added the spring security dependency in my project I got 401. So, I tried to create a config file where added the following code. However again I am getting 401.

Below is my code for the configuration file. Let me know if I am missing something.

```
package com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    try {
        System.out.println("filtering certain requests");
        return httpSecurity.csrf()
        .disable()          
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/api/user/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Bean
public UserSecurity getUserSecurity() {
    return new UserSecurity();
}
}
```

This is the code for the service class :

```
package com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.config.UserSecurity;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.dto.PermissionDto;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.dto.UserDto;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.mapper.PermissionMapper;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.mapper.RoleMapper;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.model.Permission;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.model.Role;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.model.UserModel;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

private final UserMapper userMapper;
private final RoleMapper roleMapper;
private final PermissionMapper permissionMapper;
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
private final UserSecurity userSecurity;
public String createAdmin(UserDto userDto)
{
    UserModel userModel = userMapper.map(userDto);
    Role role = roleRepository.findAdminRole();
    userModel.setEncryptedPassword(userSecurity.getPasswordEncoder().encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    userModel.setRole(role);
    userRepository.save(userModel);
    return "created";
}

public String createCustomer(UserDto userDto)
{
    UserModel userModel = userMapper.map(userDto);
    Role role = roleRepository.findCustomerRole();
    userModel.setEncryptedPassword(userSecurity.getPasswordEncoder().encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    userModel.setRole(role);
    userRepository.save(userModel);
    return "created";
}


}
```

And this is the code for the controller class :

```
package com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.dto.UserDto;
import com.hasti.birdy.portfolio.user.service.UserService;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

private final UserService userService;
@PostMapping("/hsstudio/admin")
public ResponseEntity<String> createAdmin(@RequestBody UserDto userDto)
{
    userService.createAdmin(userDto);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("created Admin");
}
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(@RequestBody UserDto userDto)
{
    userService.createCustomer(userDto);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("created customer ");
}

    }
```

Comment: add code as text (not images), also give us more info on how you sent the request and actual path u used (images for that would be useful)

Comment: @AhmedNabil as requested I added the code in text form and code for controller and service class.

Comment: Why you are creating ```UserSecurity``` Bean?

Comment: that is to return passoword encoder @GD07. But I don't think it is causing the trouble. Is it ?

Comment: Seems, there is no trouble with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the code something like this, for me it is working fine in my local.

*Here, any request matching the url `/api/user/**` is allowed, for other url's, asking for the authentication.*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(x -> x.requestMatchers("/api/user/**")
                                    .permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue resolved now, it was because csrf was enabled. So i added .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);  and it worked

Comment: @AshishTripathi yeah right ```csrf``` should be disabled, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

one problem I've noticed you've missed @Bean on SecurityFilterChain method

```
>> @Bean <<
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        .....
}
```